# Getting errors while adding crystal reports to my visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

Type 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer'
Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument'

[image]

already added references for crystal report.

Comment: Are you able to see Crystal in your Visual options?Like Add new item?

Answer (score 0):

acctually i forgot to change the .net framework from client profile to .net framework 4